# How i can Get character input from user without using character variable in c?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    void * p;   
    p = calloc(100,sizeof(char)) ;
    scanf("%s",p) ; 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

The above code works perfectly. But I want to know if there is other possible ways ? to get char , int , float etc without using corresponding data type variables in c.

Comment: Why? Looks like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: How can you say it works perfectly when the compiler generates: warning C4477: 'scanf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'void *' ?

Answer (score 1):

The most basic method is to use `getchar`:

```
int main() {
    int c = getchar();
}
```

It reads from `stdin` one character at a time. Then you can write your own parsing logic to parse integers, floats, strings, etc.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the function return type is `int getchar()` and not `char`.

Comment: @WeatherVane fair point! `getchar` returns `EOF` when there are no more characters, which is outside of the range of `char`.

Comment: `EOF` is not outside the range of `signed char` but it is out of the range of `unsigned char`, and, cannot be distinguished from the value `0xFF` read from file.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the range of `int` contains the range of `unsigned char`, and `-1` is outside of this range. Of course if you cast -1 to `unsigned char`, it would become 0xFF and you won't be able to tell the difference between EOF and reading the byte 0xFF.